# Alert does not display in JSON callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm sure there is a simple explanation to this. I am having problems understanding why the following alert does not display in my javascript:

```
<script>
   theURL = "gb.json?callback=?";
   $.getJSON(theURL, null, function(data) {
      alert('in json proc');
   });
</script>
```

the file gb.json is in the same folder as the html containing the script. When I run it in Firebug it gets a return code of 200 OK and I see the contents of gb.json.

This must be something very simple that I'm missing. The alert should display, shouldn't it?

Comment: `data` is not valid JSON.  More specifically, `gb.json` is not returning properly formatted JSON or is not set up to handle the callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your server is returning regular JSON, not JSONP. Just pass the URL directly, without the added `callback` query string:

```
$.getJSON('gb.json', function(data) {
    alert('in json proc');
});
```

Comment: Aha! So it's the server that gb.json is on?

Comment: @user1750649: The `callback=?` part makes jQuery think you want to make a JSONP call (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) instead of doing an Ajax request and getting JSON. While the names are similar, both techniques are completely different and responses are evaluated in different ways.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I think I got confused because I was doing JSONP calls to other locations and thought this one would work the same way. Obviously not!